# displaying variables using json in php codeigniter not working

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a simple json code to fetch details from a website and my controller is like below:

```
public function trackinsert()
{

    $data = array();
    $awb = $this->input->post('awb');
    if($awb == ""){
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'Please enter AWB number'));
        exit;
    }

    $in = array("AwbNumber" =>array($awb));

    $post_data = json_encode($in);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://portal.teamex.ae/webservice/GetTracking",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Content-Type: application/json",
                                    "API-KEY:ff839ddcd02d22d5d7042d457ae04173",
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $data = base64_encode($response);
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'msg' => $response, 'segment' => $data));

    $result = base64_decode($data);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    / exit;

    $this->load->view('teamxtrackresult', array('data' => $result));
}
```

this is giving me all the data being displayed in json format but as in controller i tried to get it specific variable and display it in view like below is not working:

```
<p>AwbNumber: <span id="code"><?php echo $data->awb_number ?></span></p>
```

its just giving me an error:

> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$awb_number

can anyone please tell me how to display the values in view using variables, thanks in advance

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Is this $this->input->post('awb'); what you are expecting to show ?

Comment: @GazmendSahiti its the value from user, when user submits its, the controller will use json to fetch data from the website and show result

Comment: do a simple `print_r($data);` and find out what the data structure looks like

Comment: @RiggsFolly i get this error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for response format by printing in view page

use this to print the response coming from controller to view
in teamxtrackresult.php insert this line print_r($data);

you will get the total data coming from controller to view

if data is coming in array, you need to use $data['awb_number']. if it has multiple values in array you can use key index to print. for example $data[0]['awb_number'].

Comment: i get this error AwbNumber:
Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array when i use $data['awb_number']

Comment: can you please provide the response when you prints using print_r($data);

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string i get this error

Comment: please try to print in controller

$result = base64_decode($data);
$result = json_decode($result);
print_r($result);

Comment: i get same error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: print here
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($response);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

Comment: i get  this {\"success\":1,\"message\":\"Success\",\"TrackResponse\":[{\"Shipment\":{\"awb_number\":\"ORG30082869\",\"current_status\":\"Request Submitted\",\"status_datetime\":\"2021-09-29 13:36:17\",\"ShipmentAddress\":{\"address\":\"Mozna Building, POBox 235371\",\"city\":\"Dubai\",\"country\":\"United Arab Emirates\"},\"AwbPdf\":\"https:\\\/\\\/portal.teamex.ae\\\/webservice\\\/GetPdf\\\/T1JHMzAwODI4NjktVEVBTUVY\",\"Activity\":[{\"datetime\":\"2021-09-29 13:36:17\",\"status\":\"Submitted\",\"details\":\"Shipment at Collection Point\",\"location\":\"Customer Location\"}]}}]}","segment":"

Comment: change the line in controller

$result = base64_decode($data);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($result['TrackResponse'][0]['Shipment']['awb_number']);

in view you can print like print_r($data['TrackResponse'][0]['Shipment']['awb_number']);

Comment: i get undefine varilable $result in view

Comment: can you please come on anydesk

Comment: in view you need to use $data instead of $result

Comment: mention anydesk id. i will come at 7:30